# English translation of book by Jean-Pierre Serre?

Tags: reference-request

> > I need the english translation of the article (or book) by jean-Pierre Serre in French on the topic Homologie singulière des espaces fibrés
> >     I am interested in understanding about this conjecture: there exist infinitely many geodesics between two points on a closed Riemannian manifold. 
> >     Does there exist a translation?

Links to the French original:

On JSTOR http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1969485?uid=3738016&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102499009897

or see also http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/serre.pdf‎

Related post: [Translations of Serre's early spectral sequences papers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118425/translations-of-serres-early-spectral-sequences-papers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Translations of Serre's early spectral sequences papers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118425/translations-of-serres-early-spectral-sequences-papers)

Comment: To close this because it would be "unclear what you're asking" strikes me as rather odd.

Comment: How about the manifold $S^1$? I think you may need to consider your intended question more carefully

Comment: I voted to close because this question does not show adequate care or forethought before asking it, see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/203

Comment: $S^1$ is fine: take the segment between the points and concatenate with multiples of the closed geodesic. This is a problem of critical points in the loop space, so going around many times is allowed.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva OK, I misunderstood the question, rhanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is Serre's Ph.D. thesis; it has been translated into english but only the introduction is available for free:

http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/8444/suppl_file/8444_chap01.pdf

the remaining 100  pages are behind a £ 20 paywall:

http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789814401319_0001